# NSIS executes exe but not running the exe

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm currently trying to compile an installer with NSIS but it is not working properly. I have the code:

```
Section "Main" MAIN ; installs the primary

    DetailPrint "Starting setup..."
    SectionIn RO
    File "setup.exe"
    ExecWait "$INSTDIR\setup.exe"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\setup.exe"

SectionEnd
```

The finished installer says that it is executing setup.exe but it is not opening and almost immediately after the log message it says that the installer has finished. I was previously using exactly this code to install an example executable but now I cannot get it to run. The executable works fine outside of NSIS. Does anyone have any ideas as to why my installer will not run the executable file?

Comment: Some error in setup.exe when running within NSIS?  Have setup.exe log its progress in detail?  Are you sure that $INSTDIR\setup.exe is the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a call to `SetOutPath` anywhere, are you sure setup.exe actually exists?

A minimal example would be:

```
OutFile test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user
InstallDir $temp\Test

Section
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $pluginsdir
File "setup.exe"
ExecWait "$pluginsdir\setup.exe"
Delete "$pluginsdir\setup.exe"
SetOutPath $Temp ; Don't lock pluginsdir
SectionEnd
```

The other reason ExecWait might fail is if the thing you are starting requires elevation and you are not elevated, then you must use ExecShell...